# Single Linked List Insert method Termination in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
void insert()
{
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *tmp;
    int i;
    int value;
    int position;

    temp = head;
    printf("Enter a value to be inserted into the linked list");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    printf("Enter at which postion of the linked list to be added");
    scanf("%d", &position);
    printf("%d\t", position);
    printf("%d\t", head);
    printf("%d\t", temp);
    printf("%d\t", value);

    for (i = 1; i < position; i++)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    tmp->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->next->data = value;
    temp->next->next = tmp->next;
}
```

This is insert function I have built for single linked list, but it is in turn giving me segmentation fault.

Comment: Haven't I seen this already some hours ago?

Comment: `tmp->next=temp->next;` : `tmp` is uninitialized variable.

Comment: You should learn how to properly indent your code to make it readable (I fixed it for you this time). `temp = temp->next;` what if `temp` is NULL?

Comment: What if someone enters `"ten"` for the `value` or `position`? ***Always*** validate all *User Input*.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert a new node at the head of a single linked list, then you have to allocate a new node first and set its data:

```
struct node *newNode;
newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Then the original header of the list becomes the successor of the new node and the new node becomes the new head of the list:

```
newNode->next = head;
head = newNode;
```